# Subquery instead of column name vs Inner Join

Tags: subquery

I'm fairly new to SQL and have started running into sub-queries as in this query below:

```
SELECT  C.CustomerID
,       C.Name
,       ( Select  PhoneNumber
          FROM    PhoneNumberTable P
          WHERE   P.CustomerID = C.CustomerID ) AS "PhoneNumber"
FROM    CustomerTable C
```

Comparing to this query with a join below:

```
SELECT  C.CustomerID
,       C.Name
,       P.PhoneNumber
FROM    CustomerTable C

JOIN    PhoneNumberTable P
ON  P.customerID = C.customerID
```

Is there a difference in terms of efficiency/speed? The SQL I am working with has several sub-queries as I have shown above (no JOINs) and it is difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

joins in my experience tend to be faster, but sometimes you need a subquery.

you should also look into [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) they are very usefull and much easier (in my opinion) to manage

in your specific case i would use a join... because you are trying to join the 2 tables together.